# Trapezoid Length Relationships

Tags: geometry

The figure shows a trapezoid $ABCD$ where $AB  = 2$ and $DC = 3$. Given that $E$ is the midpoint of $AB$, what are the ratios $AF:FG:GC$?

[image: Trapezoid ABCD]

I can see by triangle similarity that:

- $AF = FC/3$
- $AG = 2GC/3$

What can I use to find a relationship between $AF$ and $AG$?

Comment: If $|AC|=x$, you've practically proven that $|AF|=\frac{1}{4}x$ and $|AG|=\frac{2}{5}x$ so $|FG|=\left(\frac{2}{5}-\frac{1}{4}\right)x=\frac{3}{20}x$ etc. So, $|AF|:|FG|:|GC|=5:3:12$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you for the prompt reply! You did clear it up first, do you want to post as answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1):

$\triangle AFE \sim \triangle CFD$ and $\triangle AGB \sim \triangle CGD$ (AAA similarity)

Let $AC=20x$

$\frac{AF}{FC}=\frac{AE}{DC}=\frac{1}{3}=\frac{5x}{15x}$

$\frac{AG}{GC}=\frac{AB}{DC}=\frac{2}{3}=\frac{8x}{12x}$

$FG=AG-AF=8x-5x=3x$

$AF:FG:GC=5:3:12$